# How to wait until getAttribute return specific string (text) in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question.
In a page that I am testing their is a field, that include .
I want selenium to wait until

```
getWebDriver().findElement((locator)).getAttribute("value");
```

will return a certain text.
is their a way to selenium wait until getAttribute will return a custom text?

this is the dome
[image]
this is the screen
[image]
I want selenium to wait until BBBOOBP displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Selenium web driver explicit wait conditions to wait till element with text be present in DOM.

**Official documentation with the sample in different languages:**
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait

Let me know if that doesn't help you.

Comment: this is the problem getText() is not what I need it returned null, I need something to get attribute function.   all the waits are for get text I need to get attribute

Comment: you can change your xpath according to text and see wait till its visibility.
selenium also provides attribute based waits to:

ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(locator, attribute, value)
ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(locator, attribute, value)

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem

```
 public void waitForElementAttributeEqualsString(By locator, String expectedString)
    {
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, EXPLICIT_WAITE);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> elementAttributeEqualsString = arg0 -> element.getAttribute("value").equals
                (expectedString);
        wait.until(elementAttributeEqualsString);
    }
```